# What is involved in the film/sound synchronization process?

Tags: audio

The title says it all: what is involved in synchronizing a film's audio and visual elements, particularly in regard to music.

Given 30 seconds of video and 30 seconds of music meant to accompany it, is the process any more complex that making sure the two tracks start at the same time?

Presumably there's also an issue of cutting film and sound and re-aligning them.

But at core, is it more than aligning start points? And if yes, how so?

Comment: The one thing you don't want is some damn director re-cutting after you submitted all your cues :\ There's nothing less fun than re-arranging everything with awkward 7/8 & 17/16 bars just so your hits still match.

Comment: I'd bet that you also have to align the end points and several intermediate points (think YouTube video playback syncing).

Comment: In the old times, begin and end points were aligned using a clapboard!

Comment: This question needs more details. Are you asking about actual celluloid film? There are many formats, some include the audio as an optical track so it is always in perfect sync. You also mentioned video, so what format, codec, etc.?